# How to retrieve NTFS File attributes in C#

Tags: c#, ntfs, file-attributes

I was really surprised when I found out, that I did not find any way to read all NTFS attributes. I can access some attributes through the following lines:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Get Attributes for file.
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"C:\Testfiles\test.xls");
    FileAttributes attributes = info.Attributes;
    Console.WriteLine(attributes);

    // Get Attributes for directory.
    info = new FileInfo("C:\\");
    attributes = info.Attributes;
    Console.WriteLine(attributes);
}
```

[image: Text]

The "info" object now has some interesting values like the last modified date etc. But what if I want to read all NTFS attributes like in this picture?

I googled a lot, but could not find anything easy? Do you know any way?
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/troubleshoot/office/dsofile.dll-allow-edit-document-property) is unfortunately only for office documents- but I want to edit all ntfs file attributes.

Comment: Type "MS Excel..." is not NTFS attribute. It is info from file association / Registry. `FileInfo` object has to include creation, last modification, and last access date and time. Interesting NTFS attributes are whether file is compressed or encrypted (EFS).

Comment: Yeah - makes sense... but how could I retrieve all attributes added by office?